# jquery click function to autoclick on two buttons to open two windows in different targets

Tags: php, jquery

I want make a php program which onload will autoclick on two buttons to open two windows on two different targets. For this I tried the following jquery function

```
jQuery(function(){
jQuery('#pp1', '#qq1').click();});



echo "<input type='submit' value='Prepare Exam Related Documents1 '   name='sw8' style='font-size:2.5ex' id='pp1'>";

echo "<input type='submit' value='Prepare Exam Related Documents2' name='sw9' style='font-size:2.5ex' id='qq1'>";
```

I have also tried

```
jQuery(function(){
jQuery('.pp1').click();});
echo "<input type='submit' value='Prepare Exam Related Documents1' name='sw8' style='font-size:2.5ex' class='pp1'>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Prepare Exam Related Documents2' name='sw9' style='font-size:2.5ex' class='pp1'>";
```

But I could not achieve my targets.
Please suggest me something

Comment: `$('input[type="submit"]').click();`?

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#pp1').trigger('click');
  $('#qq1').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Doublecheck the ids of your inputs and match them with the jquery code

Comment: Checked but could not find out where is the mistake